# Github disable delete local branch

Tags: github

If I fork a repository I have permission to that is owned by a company into my personal github, make some changes, make a PR, sometimes my collaborators (the ones in charge of the PR) will click "merge and delete local branch". This deletes the branch out of my private github account. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Are you sure that it works that way? I would be very surprised if it was.

Comment: Yes, there is an option, upon closing the PR, called "Close and delete branch". Presumably used for small feature branches.

Comment: I don't doubt that there's an option to do that. What surprises me is that it removes a branch *from your fork*.

Comment: It surprises me as well. I think it is because the company owns the repo, which I forked, so they have a right to delete all forks/branches as well. This is a privately owned repo not a public repo.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no way to disable it, a workaround would be to create a branch referencing the same HEAD as the feature branch used for the PR (and which gets deleted when merged in the original repo).

That would allow you to keep track of that feature branch, even after the PR has been completed.